# Counting the number of unread messages for a user

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have done a fair amount of googling, but I can't seem to get this one right..

I have three tables:

comm_messages:

```
- room_id:integer
- created_at:datetime
```

comm_visitors:

```
- room_id:integer
- user_id:integer
- updated_at:datetime
```

I want to find out for a given user_id, how many new messages (the ones that were created after the user visited the room) are there?

### Example

If I have this kind of data:

comm_messages:

```
+---------+------------------+
| room_id |    created_at    |
+---------+------------------+
|   1     |   20.11.2018     |
|   1     |   20.12.2018     |
|   2     |   21.12.2018     |
|   3     |   24.12.2018     |
|   4     |   19.05.2018     |
+---------+------------------+
```

comm_visitors:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| user_id | room_id | updated_at |
+---------+---------+------------+
|    1    |    1    | 03.11.2018 |
|    1    |    3    | 25.12.2018 |
|    1    |    4    | 11.05.2018 |
|    2    |    1    | 01.01.2019 |
|    2    |    2    | 03.11.2018 |
|    2    |    4    | 03.11.2018 |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

For `user_id = 1` I should get `3` and for `user_id = 2` I should get `2`.

My current attempt has been revolving around something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(comm_messages.id) 
  FROM comm_messages LEFT JOIN comm_visitors 
   ON comm_messages.room_id = comm_visitors.room_id 
  WHERE comm_visitors.user_id = 1 
   AND comm_visitors.updated_at > comm_messages.updated_at;
```

But that's no good..

Comment: please include some sample data and the expected result

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala added

Answer (score 1):

I think you are pretty close.  This should do what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT v.user_id, v.room_id, MAX(v.updated_at) as last_visit
      FROM comm_visitors v
      WHERE v.user_id = 1
      GROUP BY v.user_id, v.room_id
     ) v JOIN
     comm_messages m
     ON m.room_id = v.room_id AND
        v.last_visit > m.updated_at;
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment, you should be able to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM comm_visitors v JOIN
     comm_messages m
     ON m.room_id = v.room_id AND
        v.updated_at > m.updated_at
WHERE v.user_id = 1
```

Comment: why MAX(v.updated_at) ? user_id + room_id combination for visitors is unique

Comment: @Almaron . . . That is not obvious from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, but to get the unread messages you need to look for messages created after / "greater than" the user's visit time, like so:

```
select count(1)
from comm_visitors v
join comm_messages  m on v.room_id = m.room_id 
 --only include messages created _after_ the last visit
 and v.updated_at < m.created_at
where v.user_id = 1
```

If you want to include messages in rooms the user has never visited as unread, you can use something like:

```
select count(1)
from comm_messages m
left join comm_visitors v on v.room_id = m.room_id and v.user_id = 1
where m.created_at > coalesce(v.updated_at, '1900-01-01')
```